# Python Tkinter, setting up button callback functions with a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm writing a program that displays a grid of buttons, when a button is pressed I want it to print the location of the button in the grid ("row column") out to the console. Here is what I have

```
import Tkinter as tk

class board(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.rows = 5
        self.columns = 5
        self.init_board()

    def init_board(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.columns):
                cmd = lambda: self.button_callback(i,j)
                b = tk.Button(self, text=str("  "), command=cmd)
                b.grid(row=i, column=j)

    def button_callback(self, row, col):
        print(str(row) + " " + str(col))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    board().mainloop()
```

the problem is that when I click on any of the buttons I get "4 4" printed out which is the location of the last button instantiated in the loop. I don't know why this is happening, please help!

Answer (score 7):

In the function created using `lambda`, `i`, `j` refers to the varaible in the `init_board` function, which are set to 4, 4 after the `for` loop ends.

You can workaround this using default argument.

---

Replace the following line:

```
cmd = lambda: self.button_callback(i,j)
```

with:

```
cmd = lambda i=i, j=j: self.button_callback(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what [@falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) has said, You can also use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```py
from functools import partial
# ...
cmd = partial(self.button_callback, i, j)
# ...
```

Or you can "emulate" `partial`'s behavior like this: (use this snippet instead of the import statement)

```py
def partial(fn, i, j):
    def nested():
        fn(i, j)
    return nested
```

A better "emulation" can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).