# Working with time delay and list in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

My problem with my code is that I want to update my list during the delay and make the label appear twice with different values. I want b to appear first and then d will appear later. But it seems that only d is displayed now. 
Is there any ways that I can go around it?
Any help is much appreciated!

```
import Tkinter as tk

a_list=["a","b","c"]
root=tk.Tk()
variableone=tk.StringVar()
label1=tk.Label(root,text="appear later")
label1.pack()
label=tk.Label(root, textvariable=variableone)
label.after(2000, lambda:variableone.set(a_list[1]))
label.pack()

a_list[1]="d"
label.after(5000, lambda:variableone.set(a_list[1]))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to your `lambda`s using the *current* value of `a_list[1]` when they're called, not the value it had when the`lambda`s were created. You can get around that by giving them a default argument, since that's only evaluated at creation time.

This is a common problem when using `lambda`s as callback functions. See [Python Tkinter, setting up button callback functions with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20717203/4014959) for a similar problem using `lambda`s to set up a series of Button widgets in a loop.

This code does what you want. It uses `s` as the default argument to hold the value of `a_list[1]`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

a_list=["a","b","c"]
root=tk.Tk()
variableone=tk.StringVar()
label1=tk.Label(root,text="appear later")
label1.pack()
label=tk.Label(root, textvariable=variableone)
label.after(2000, lambda s=a_list[1]:variableone.set(s))
label.pack()

a_list[1]="d"
label.after(5000, lambda s=a_list[1]:variableone.set(s))

root.mainloop()
```